# Add Rank column by select result group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, rank

I have a table named myTable  which contains a list of participants and theirs scores in each test.

```
-----------------------------------------
id_test     id_paticipant   score
-----------------------------------------
id_test1    Partcipant1      100
id_test1    Partcipant2      200
id_test1    Partcipant3      150
id_test1    Partcipant4      300
id_test2    Partcipant1      500
id_test2    Partcipant3      250
id_test3    Partcipant2       70
id_test3    Partcipant3      150
id_test3    Partcipant4      420
id_test4    Partcipant1      120
id_test4    Partcipant2      200
```

I want to have a request which permits me to have a rank colum in whitch i will have the rank of each participant in each test like the table below.

```
-----------------------------------------------
id_test     id_paticipant   score   rank
-------------------------------------------------------
id_test1    Partcipant1      100    4
id_test1    Partcipant2      200    2
id_test1    Partcipant3      150    3
id_test1    Partcipant4      300    1
id_test2    Partcipant1      500    1
id_test2    Partcipant3      250    2
id_test3    Partcipant2       70    3
id_test3    Partcipant3      150    2
id_test3    Partcipant4      420    1
id_test4    Partcipant1      120    2
id_test4    Partcipant2      200    1
---------------------------------------------
```

i have try this :

```
SET @prev_id_test := 0;
SET @curRow := 1;
select t2.id_test, t2.id_partcipant, t2.score
,if(t2.id_test=@prev_id_test, @curRow := @curRow + 1, @curRow := 1) AS rank, @prev_id_test := t2.id_test 
from (select myTable.* from myTable order by myTable.id_test, myTable.score desc) as t2 
order by t2.id_test, t2.score, t2.id_partcipant desc;
```

But it doesn't work, i have the rank in decreasing order, I mean the least score has the rank 1, etc... like :

```
-----------------------------------------------
id_test     id_paticipant   score   rank
-----------------------------------------------
id_test1    Partcipant1      100    1
id_test1    Partcipant2      200    3
id_test1    Partcipant3      150    2
id_test1    Partcipant4      300    4
id_test2    Partcipant1      500    2
id_test2    Partcipant3      250    1
id_test3    Partcipant2       70    1
id_test3    Partcipant3      150    2
id_test3    Partcipant4      420    3
id_test4    Partcipant1      120    1
id_test4    Partcipant2      200    2
---------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help please ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@it = t.id_test, @rn + 1,
                  if(@it := t.id_test, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rank
from (select t.*
      from myTables t
      order by id_test, score desc
     ) t cross join
     (select @it := -1, @rn := 0) params;
```

What is the difference?  Your version is assigning variables and referring to them in different expressions.  MySQL (nor any other database) guarantees the order of evaluation of expressions in the `SELECT`.  So, you don't know which occurs first.

And, MySQL v8+ finally makes the use of variables unnecessary.  It has joined the rest of the SQL community in supporting window functions.  This simplifies the logic to:

```
row_number() over (partition by test_id order by score_desc) as ranking
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff it's working. However, I stil not knowing what is wrong with my version ? Can you explain me what you are doing in this part of your code : if(@it := t.id_test, 1, 1).  I'll test the other solution with mysql v8. Tha,ks again

Comment: @Xeuch . . . Your version is assigning and using variables in multiple expressions in the `SELECT`.  These can be evaluated in any order.

Answer (score 0):

I want now to add 3 other columns:

- Max which contains the max score of each group,
- Min which contain the min score of each group,
- and average which contains the average score of each group

Like this table shown here:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
id_test     id_participant  score   rank    Max   Min   average
------------------------------------------------------------------------
id_test1    Partcipant1      100     4      300   100    187.5
id_test1    Partcipant2      200     2      300   100    187.5
id_test1    Partcipant3      150     3      300   100    187.5
id_test1    Partcipant4      300     1      300   100    187.5
id_test2    Partcipant1      500     1      500   250    375
id_test2    Partcipant3      250     2      500   250    375
id_test3    Partcipant2       70     3      420    70    213.33
id_test3    Partcipant3      150     2      420    70    213.33
id_test3    Partcipant4      420     1      420    70    213.33
id_test4    Partcipant1      120     2      200   120    160
id_test4    Partcipant2      200     1      200   120    160
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I try this :

```
select  
    t.*,
    (@rn := if(@it = t.id_test, @rn + 1,if(@it := t.id_test, 1, 1))) as rank,
    (select max(t1.score) from myTables t1 group by t1.id_test) as Max,
    (select min(t1.score) from myTables t1 group by t1.id_test) as Max,
    (select round((sum(t1.score)/count(t1.id_participant)), 2) from myTables t1 group by t1.id_test) as average
from
    (select t.* 
     from myTables 
     order by t.id_test, t.score desc) as t 
cross join 
    (select @it := -1, @rn := 0) params;
```

But I get this error:

> Can't reopen table

I think that it is caused by the fact that the table myTable is a temporary table.

Do you have some ideas ?

Thanks